# UNIX: Unexpected End of file

Tags: linux, unix

I have a problem where the editor reports no problems, but when I run it in a terminal, it reports: Unexpected end of file.

What I'm trying to do is get it so that when this script is run, it  changes the permissions so that everyone can execute the file.

I'm scripting the file on a Windows Machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=~\scripts\chmxtextfile.txt

if [[  -e "$file"  ]];   
then {chmod ugo+x $file} 
elif [[  ! -e "$file"  ]];
then echo "File doesn't exist"
fi
```

Comment: You need space after `{` and a semicolon before `}`.

Comment: File paths on *nix are / delimited, not \

Comment: Don't bother checking existence, just run `chmod`.  If the file doesn't exist `chmod` will emit the error message for you.

Comment: You say you're scripting on Windows, but tagged with Linux and Unix.  Does that mean you have CRLF line endings in the script and they're causing grief?  Also, the backslashes are aconventional for Unix-ish environments, and on Windows you can use `/` instead of `\`. At least be cautious about the use of backslashes. Note that the `elif` could be simply `else`; the result will only be unexpected if something changes the existence state of the file between the first and second tests. The semicolons are unnecessary with the code as written; they'd be necessary if the `then` appeared on the line.

Comment: You should double quote the file name in `chmod ugo+x "$file"`.

Comment: How are you running a bash script on a Windows machine? There are several ways to do that (Cygwin is probably the most common); which one you're using could be very relevant.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Just running `chmod` *might* be sufficient, but you might want to distinguish between `chmod` failing because the file doesn't exist and `chmod` failing for some other reason (say, because you don't have permission).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Quoting backslashes in Markdown is tricky. You meant to write that you can use `/` instead of ``\``. (It took a few tries to get the formatting right.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: yes, and I wasn't paying attention to the formatting until after the time-to-edit window closed, so I have to live with the mess (or delete and re-enter the comment).  Sorry for my lapse of attention.